# Regarding pointers and segmentation-faults

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Question regarding pointers and segmentation-faults.

Comment: while (*id_character == 'c') { // What if there us no 'c' 
      *id_character = '6';
      id_character--; // probably end up reading illegar memory causing segfault
    }

Comment: The program is set up such that the inputs to next_commit_id are strings containing 0's, 1's, 6's, and c's, so I don't think that's what's causing the issue. It might have something to do with *id_character though. I tried freeing the pointer from memory before the function terminated, but that gave an error as well.

Comment: That's why its a comment :) .@Jonathan Leffler gave you a correct explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the line:

```
dir_name = strcat(".beargit/", commit_id);
```

You are attempting to add `commit_id` to the end of a constant string.  That string is probably in read-only memory and the attempt to modify it leads to undefined behaviour — in your case, a segmentation fault.  At best it leads to undefined behaviour, though there's a strong argument that a segmentation fault is good because you can't ignore the fact that there's a problem.

> How do I fix it?

You currently have:

```
char* dir_name = malloc(strlen(commit_id) + 10);
dir_name = strcat(".beargit/", commit_id);
```

If you didn't crash, you'd be leaking the newly allocated memory.  You should be using:

```
char* dir_name = malloc(strlen(commit_id) + 10);
if (dir_name == 0)
    …report error and exit…Do not pass Go; Do not collect $200…
strcpy(dir_name, ".beargit/");
strcat(dir_name, commit_id);
```

Or:

```
sprint(dir_name, ".beargit/%s", commit_id);
```

No doubt other ways could be found too.  I'd be strongly tempted to replace the `10` in the `malloc()` with `sizeof(".beargit/")` which is the correct size; the `sizeof()` operator includes the terminal null in the length it returns.

Don't forget to release the allocated memory!

Comment: So how do I fix this? Do I create a char* variable and assign ".beargit/" to be its value?

Comment: Error handling Monopoly style...I like it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan Leffler pointed out correctly, ".beargit/" is read only and strcat would fail as it can not append to read-only segment.

try

```
  char breargit_buffer[256] = ".beargit/"; // allocate some large enrough non read only buffer

  dir_name = strcat(breargit_buffer, commit_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `strcat` arguments are reversed.  It is `strcat(destination, source)`

Try:

```
char buffer[SOMETHING_BIG_ENOUGH];
...
strcpy(buffer, ".beargit/");
dir_name = strcat(buffer, commit_id);
fs_mkdir(dir_name);
fs_cp(".beargit/.index", strcat(buffer, commit_id));
fs_cp(".beargit/.prev", strcat(buffer, commit_id));
```

Comment: I tried this but it just concatenated the strings in the reverse order.

Comment: Ah yes.  I updated the answer to strcpy to a buffer first.